# pass data via on-click angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a .json file with a list of cows with details about where each one lives.

I have two panels.

One panel displays the list of cows and I have this displayed using `ng-repeat`.

The second panel appears when the title of the cow is clicked on, which is all great and working. However I can't seam to work out how to pass the location of that particular cow. Is it possible to pass grab and pass the number in the cow array? I've tried passing {{'cow'}} thinking that this would represent the array id but I don't think I'm on the right track so thought I'd post up here.

Is there any way to pass the data so that only the location of the cow clicked shows up? Do I need to call a promise or something?

Thanks - code below of where I am so far

HTML

```
<html ng-app="animalApp">
<section ng-controller="AnimalController as animalCtrl">
<ul ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
  <li ng-class="{ active: panel.isSelected(1)}" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="cow in animalCtrl.cows">
        <h2>
          <a href="" data-ng-bind="cow.name" ng-click="panel.selectTab(2); cowId({{cow}})"></a>
        </h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{ active: panel.isSelected(2)}" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
    <p>This {{animalCtrl.cow.name}} lives in {{animalCtrl.cow.country}}</p>
    <a href="" ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Back to all cows</a>
  </li>
</ul> 
</section>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('animalApp', [ ]);

app.controller('AnimalController', ['$http', '$scope',function($http, $scope){
    var type = this;
    type.cows = [ ];
    $http.get('animals.json').success(function(data){
        type.cows = data;
    });

app.controller("PanelController", function() {
    this.tab = 1;
    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        this.tab = setTab;
    };
    this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
        return this.tab === checkTab;   
    }
});
```

JSON

```
[
   {
        "name": "Angus",
        "country": "UK"
   },
   {
        "name": "Hereford",
        "country": "Canada"
   },
   {
        "name": "Dwarf Lulu",
        "country": "Nepal"
   },
   {
        "name": "Ongole",
        "country": "India"
   }
]
```

Here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/gFYkeJZK2ROv4FyCEgEl?p=preview) with the additions from the submitted answers(thanks) but yet to still get it to work. When clicking on 'Angus UK. I'm aiming to have the paragraph say 'This Angus lives in UK' - which is currently does not. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: share your json structure please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass in `cow`. Based on your code, this seems to be what you want.

```
<li ng-repeat="cow in animalCtrl.cows">
    <h2>
      <a href="" data-ng-bind="cow.name" ng-click="panel.selectTab(2); animalCtrl.cowId(cow)"></a>
    </h2>
  </li>
```

controller

```
app.controller('AnimalController', ['$http', '$scope',function($http, $scope){
    var type = this;
    type.cows = [ ];
    $http.get('animals.json').success(function(data){
        type.cows = data;
    });
    type.cowId = function(cow){
        this.cow = cow;
    };
}
```

or if you wanted to pass in the index of the iterated cow

```
<li ng-repeat="cow in animalCtrl.cows">
    <h2>
      <a href="" data-ng-bind="cow.name" ng-click="panel.selectTab(2); animalCtrl.cowId($index)"></a>
    </h2>
  </li>
```

controller

```
app.controller('AnimalController', ['$http', '$scope',function($http, $scope){
    var type = this;
    type.cows = [ ];
    $http.get('animals.json').success(function(data){
        type.cows = data;
    });
    type.cowId = function(id){
        this.cow = type.cows[id];
    };
}
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZeCcHa4KCkKH1lkkuNo?p=preview)

Comment: ok, thanks - but i haven't set up a cowId function as wasn't sure how to this part... I've tried something like this in my app.js `this.cowId = function(id) {this.cow = id;}`. Then iterating {{id}} but with no luck..

Comment: Thanks but still not getting anything displaying and I've changed `
    <p>This {{animalCtrl.cow.name}} lives in {{animalCtrl.cow.country}}</p>` to  <p>This {{cow.name}} lives in {{cow.country}}</p>` in the second panel but still nothing shows up.

Comment: I have added a Plunker in my original post with the above additions but still unable to get anything to appear though. @teliren

Comment: @Barett added a plunker

Comment: @fidev 
animalCtrl.cowId(cow)  added plunkr